# Lost months with core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am storing dates in a core data data file whenever the user uses my app and then displaying them back to the user. For some reason, just every now and again, i get an entry with the the right day and year but the month has dropped back to the fires. Has anyone heard of this happening in the past and know how to fix it?
Everything seems unaffected (ie time, days and years) except month. It only ever changes to january (IE it either works right eg 23/5/2011 or it defaults to january eg 23/1/2011)
Thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this or can even point me in the right direction as to finding the problem as so far it looks random
thanks

Comment: how are you storing the date info?. Epoc offset? . String?

Comment: I am storing the actual nsdate value. It is set using `[NSDate date];`

Comment: Found my issue. It wasnt random, it only happens when i quit the app then go back in. I wasnt handeling the date correctly when i feed it back into the app. Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue. It wasn't random, it only happens when I quit the app then go back in. I wasn't handling the date correctly when I feed it back into the app.